# How to make custom multiple guard for authentication attempt with sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

accourding to this post :
[laravel-sanctum-custom-guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359429/laravel-sanctum-custom-guard)

i want to make Auth that only work for specific guard ex : Auth::guard("admin")
but default method that i know is : (only for default guard)

```
$credentials = request(['username', 'password']);
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

and also i need how to logout with specific guard

default logout user is :

```
Auth::logout();
```

i really appreciate if someone can help me coz im new with this, thankyou